# Deploy tachyon with Ansible without ssh connexion between servers i.e. how to format master

Tags: ssh, ansible, alluxio

For the moment tachyon is deploy on local mode i.e. http://tachyon-project.org/documentation/v0.7.1/Running-Tachyon-Locally.html

My main issue here is the ssh connexion. The classic way is to do:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

But I would like to not enable ssh connexion (between the servers) for the moment and only deploy services with Ansible (which have the ssh connexion authorization). So here I have to deploy all tachyon services by myself. AFAIK I have to do:

format the master and then:

```
./bin/tachyon formatWorker
./bin/tachyon-start.sh master
./bin/tachyon-start.sh worker SudoMount
```

The problem here is how to format the master. Is `./bin/tachyon format -s` enough? Or do I have to change tachyon script and add a formatMaster cmd?

Version: tachyon(0.7.1) with spark(1.5.1) on a Ubuntu server(14.04) with Ansible(1.9.2) for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following lines to handle the problem in the `bin/tachyon` script

```
elif [ "$COMMAND" == "formatMaster" ]; then
  if [ -z $TACHYON_MASTER_ADDRESS ] ; then
    TACHYON_MASTER_ADDRESS=localhost
  fi
  echo "Formatting Tachyon Master @ $TACHYON_MASTER_ADDRESS"
  CLASS=tachyon.Format
  PARAMETER=master
```